# How to focus and interact with popup using selenide api

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I have a popup screen (see attached image). I am using selenide which is a fantastic wrapper api of selenium. Can someone tell me how selenide focuses and interacts with such window popups.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work. It was an Iframe and by using

```
driver.switchTo().frame("IFrameID/name") to interact with the popup window
```

To Go back to the main frame

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent()
```